# Firestore Order By UserId with highest priority

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project in which I need to paginate through results in order to load the users with the highest priority in the DB. The else block is the initial load of users and the if block should control the pagination however I am getting empty results (0 documents) on the pagination call while getting the users successfully on the initial call.


I have 41 test documents and the limit is set to 20 so I should get 2 full pages +1 extra user on the third however I can only get the first page of (user) documents. I looked at the pagination documentation and I have already built the index for the firestore but I'm still having trouble figuring out this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
if(lastId != null){
  return store.collection("users")
         .whereEqualTo("gender", searchingFor)
         .whereEqualTo("geoHashGroup", geoHashGroup)
         .orderBy("priority")
         .orderBy("userId")
         .startAfter(lastId)
         .limit(limit)
} else {
  return store.collection("users")
         .whereEqualTo("gender", searchingFor)
         .whereEqualTo("geoHashGroup", geoHashGroup)
         .orderBy("priority")
         .limit(limit)
}
```

I set `lastId` inside of this method which is fired each time a person swipes on someone.

```
override fun onCardDisappeared(view: View?, position: Int) {
        swipedCardUser = pmList[position]
        lastId = swipedCardUser!!.userId
        if(position == pmList.lastIndex){
            Log.d("REFRESHCARDS", swipedCardUser!!.geoHashGroup!!)
            findPotentialMatches()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you set `lastId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not ordering your initial query on `userId`, which means that the database orders the documents only in priority order and returns a "random" 20 users from it. So there's no guarantee that the `userId` that you have in `lastId` is actually that of the 20th user when you order by `userId`.

The pagination queries typically are exactly the same, except for the `startAfter`, which is why I usually write them as:

```
const query = store.collection("users")
         .whereEqualTo("gender", searchingFor)
         .whereEqualTo("geoHashGroup", geoHashGroup)
         .orderBy("priority")
         .orderBy("userId")
         .limit(limit);
if(lastId != null){
  query = query.startAfter(lastId);
}
return query;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
This still doesn't seem to produce the desired result unfortunately. It looks like the startAfter is just getting the document with the lastId as it's userId and not the next set of documents.

Comment: Ah, I see.... you'll actually need to pass values for all fields that you order/filter on, not just the ID. It's typically easiest if you keep the entire `DocumentSnapshot` of the anchor document, and pass that into `startAfter()`, so `query.startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshot)`.